# Method to AsyncTask Android OAuth2Client

Tags: android, android-asynctask, oauth-2.0, token, thread-exceptions

I am trying to use this code:

```
public static Token getAccessToken(OAuth2Config oauthDetails) {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(oauthDetails.getTokenEndPointUrl());
    String clientId = oauthDetails.getClientId();
    String clientSecret = oauthDetails.getClientSecret();
    String scope = oauthDetails.getScope();
    List<BasicNameValuePair> parametersBody = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(OAuthConstants.GRANT_TYPE,
            oauthDetails.getGrantType()));
    parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(OAuthConstants.USERNAME,
            oauthDetails.getUsername()));
    parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(OAuthConstants.PASSWORD,
            oauthDetails.getPassword()));
    if (isValid(clientId)) {
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(OAuthConstants.CLIENT_ID,
                clientId));
    }
    if (isValid(clientSecret)) {
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                OAuthConstants.CLIENT_SECRET, clientSecret));
    }
    if (isValid(scope)) {
        parametersBody.add(new BasicNameValuePair(OAuthConstants.SCOPE,
                scope));
    }
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    Token accessToken = null;
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametersBody, HTTP.UTF_8));
        response = client.execute(post);
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (code >= 400) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Authorization server expects Basic authentication");
                // Add Basic Authorization header
            post.addHeader(
                    OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION,
                    getBasicAuthorizationHeader(oauthDetails.getUsername(),
                            oauthDetails.getPassword()));
            Log.d(TAG, "Retry with login credentials");
            try {
                response.getEntity().consumeContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            response = client.execute(post);
            code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (code >= 400) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Retry with client credentials");
                post.removeHeaders(OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION);
                post.addHeader(
                        OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION,
                        getBasicAuthorizationHeader(
                                oauthDetails.getClientId(),
                                oauthDetails.getClientSecret()));
                try {
                    response.getEntity().consumeContent();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                response = client.execute(post);
                code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (code >= 400) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Could not retrieve access token for user: "
                                    + oauthDetails.getUsername());
                }
            }
        }
        Map map = handleResponse(response);
        accessToken = new Token(Long.valueOf((Integer) map.get(OAuthConstants.EXPIRES_IN)), (String) map.get(OAuthConstants.TOKEN_TYPE), (String) map.get(OAuthConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN), (String) map.get(OAuthConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN));
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return accessToken;
}
```

Is part of an OAuth2Client that i am using in my Android app.
I am getting this error:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

and i was reading that i should use AsyncTask, but i have no idea how to convert this method to a AsyncTask.

I will apreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All you need a Fragment to wrap your `asynctask` so if the device rotates you do not create multiple requests and leak that. And also you need listener (`GetAccessTokenCallbacks`) to inform your activity that you have done and returning the result.

```
public class GetAccessTokenFragment extends Fragment {


OAuth2Config mOauthDetails;

static interface GetAccessTokenCallbacks {
  void onPostExecute(Token token);
}

private GetAccessTokenCallbacks mCallbacks;
private AccessTokenTask mTask;


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
  super.onAttach(activity);
  mCallbacks = (GetAccessTokenCallbacks) activity;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setRetainInstance(true);
  // you must do it as follow
  // first create new instance
  // mOauthDetails = new OAuth2Config(....)
  // then use the values of MainActivity.this.mOauthDetails to initialize it


  mTask = new AccessTokenTask();
  mTask.execute();

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
  super.onDetach();
  mCallbacks = null;
}



private class AccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Token> {

  @Override
  protected Token doInBackground(Void... param) {

    Token token = TheClassOfThisFunction.getAccessToken(mOauthDetails);
    return token;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Token token) {
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
      mCallbacks.onPostExecute(token[0]);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

and in your `MainActivity` you must implement `GetAccessTokenFragment.GetAccessTokenCallbacks` and creating the `GetAccessTokenFragment`.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GetAccessTokenFragment.GetAccessTokenCallbacks {

      public OAuth2Config mOauthDetails;

      private static final String TAG_GetAccessTokenFragment = "GetAccessToken";

      private GetAccessTokenFragment mGetAccessTokenFragment;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Initialize mOauthDetails here


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mGetAccessTokenFragment = (GetAccessTokenFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_GetAccessTokenFragment);

        if (mGetAccessTokenFragment == null) {
          mGetAccessTokenFragment = new GetAccessTokenFragment();
          fm.beginTransaction().add(mGetAccessTokenFragment, TAG_GetAccessTokenFragment).commit();
        }

      }

      @Override
      public void onPostExecute(Token token) {
          //you got your token here
      }
    }
```

**Seems that OAuthConfig is called in the following:**

```
public class OAuth2Client {
private final String username;
private final String password;
private final String clientId;
private final String clientSecret;
private final String site;
public OAuth2Client(String username, String password, String clientId, String clientSecret, String site) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    this.site = site;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public String getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}
public String getClientSecret() {
    return clientSecret;
}
public String getSite() {
    return site;
}
public Token getAccessToken() {
    OAuth2Config oauthConfig = new OAuth2Config.OAuth2ConfigBuilder(username, password, clientId, clientSecret, site)
            .grantType("password").build();
    return OAuthUtils.getAccessToken(oauthConfig);
}
```

}

Comment: My application has only 2 activities with containers for fragments, basically my app handles fragments all the time. When user press log in button, there comes a fragment called LogInFragment where user will input username and password. when user confirms username and password it calls a Dialog Fragment that just shows Login in... and there is where all the log in progress is done.

Comment: I guess i got it, i will test it now.  Basically the method i have to get the accessToken does not need to be an asyncTask but i should execute that method in the AsyncTask. did i understand it right?

Comment: Exactly, and my code just do that for you, I put your `getAccessToken` in `doInBackground` and because `doInBackground` runs on other thread (worker thread) you will get ride of that exception. because user can rotate your device and this cause another call to `getAccessToken` which I think it is not necessary I put AsyncTask into a retained fragment to just request one time.

Comment: this line complains:
mCallbacks.onPostExecute(token[0]);

Array typed expected, found: com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.Token

Comment: ok, i will explain how my app works:
There is an Activity, used only as a container  for the fragments.
From LogInFragment i get username and password that i pass as arguments to the DialogFragment where the validation and token should be implemented. I should initialize the OAuth2Client with all parameters and then call the getAccessToken. if i get token, storage in share preferences and go to the next activity witch will contain a new different fragment.

Comment: So far i think is working. if i enter wrong user and password, is crashing, but if i enter correct ones is working.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I can not help you right now, I have to deliver a lot of work just this Monday and I can not debug it, sorry but If you have any problem ask I will look at it when find some free time.

Comment: Do you know how i can use this inside a Dialog Fragment? of course i do have an Activity but is just the container for all the fragments. instead of creating a fragment, create a DialogFragment with layout Login in... (I did implement already). and to get the onPostExecute(token) in the Dialog fragment, not in the activity.

Comment: the first `protected void onPostExecute(Token token)` delivers the result to the fragment, I think you can replace that fragment by DialogFragment but I am not sure that DialogFragment retains its state  during configuration change or not, so read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307390/dialogfragment-disappears-on-rotation-despite-setretaininstancetrue) so delete `setRetainInstance(true);`