# In which situation we want to add fragment without container?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragment transaction has method  [add(Fragment fragment, String tag)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29), which does not place fragment to container, so it cannot have view. For what it can be used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the Android Documentation:

> However, a fragment is not required to be a part of the activity layout; you may also use a fragment without its own UI as an invisible worker for the activity.

How about this purpose ?

Simple example: an `Activity` starts an `AsyncTask`, but when device rotated `activity` restarts, causing `AsyncTask` to lose connection with the UI Thread. But this `Activity` can hold a `Fragment` (invisible, with no UI at all) that can handle all the `AsyncTask` work. When `Activity` recreated the Android OS takes care reattaching the `Fragment`, thus no data loss will occur.

Comment: are not Handlers, asynctask and services are maid wor that purpose? Or there is situation, when fragment as worker is better then any of above. Its hard for me to figure it out, as fragment runs in main thread

Comment: You've asked and answered your own question in the same comment :) ("as fragment runs in main thread")

Comment: I ment, may be there is good example which utilise fragment lifecycle with combination of asynctask or `Thread`. But it does not seem that such fragment ever has on pause and resume calls

Answer (score 6):

For Dialogs you don't have any container on normal app layer. It is directly added on Window with WindowManager(See [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) for various types of layers).

DialogFragment has an API like [DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String)) which corresponds to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fragments without UI (container) as a background worker (one benefit is that you can retain it during rotations etc) and for retaining data during rotations and other changes.

Reading http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html is strongly recommended.

Example of instance retaining: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.java

Also, here are similar questions (so this questions seems to be a duplicated but cannot be flagged due to bounty):

- [What is the use case for a Fragment with no UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531648/what-is-the-use-case-for-a-fragment-with-no-ui)
- [Android non-UI Fragment usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335796/android-non-ui-fragment-usage)

Answer (score 2):

As @Lucius Hipan mentions, it can be used to prevent data loss.
Almost always this king of fragments are used as Retained container ( setRetainInstance(true) called in onCreate method), then after device configuration changes (e.g. orientation changing) fragment will not be recreated but remembers previous state.
It's recommended way to use asynctask.

Here is an example:

There is  login activity. The user enters their credentials and presses the Login button. After that configuration change occurs (user rotates phone). So, network task was completed, but your handlers was not listening for it now. If you show any login animation, it can be stored via savedInstance, but listeners not. And instead of creating service you can simply create new retained fragment with persistant asynctask and interface to communicate with activity.

This method is a good compromise for small projects where using bus libraries is overstatement.

Answer (score 0):

By calling the method `add(Fragment fragment, String tag)` internally calls  `add(int containerId, Fragment fragment, String tag)` with a 0 containerId.That will be `add(0, fragment, tag).`

If 0 is supplied as `containerId`, it will not be placed the fragment in a container.

Comment: It is same, i wrote in question, is not it?