# "Activity has been destroyed" after device rotation using map with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting this exception after trying to rotate device:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed.
```

In my `OnCreate()` I am doing simple:

```
FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
_myMapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
fragTx.Replace(Resource.Id.map, _myMapFragment, "map");
fragTx.Commit();
```

and I am also trying to remove mapfragment in my `OnDestroy()`, like this:

```
FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragTx.Remove(_myMapFragment);
fragTx.CommitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue.

Here is how my `Main.axml` looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:hint="Nazwa ulicy w Warszawie"
        android:id="@+id/txtTextSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/txtTextSearch"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
<Button
    android:text="Moja lokalizacja"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/btnLocalizeMe"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
```

And header of my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, 
    GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, 
    GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener, 
    ILocationListener
```

Comment: take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800192/illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed-when-getsupportfragmentman)

Comment: please update full trace log,would be helpful for tracing what issue you have faced?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

and in Activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then u have to decrease the size of images only.it is exceeding heap memory.That's error is coming

Comment: This flag is not recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396892/androidlargeheap-true-in-mainifast-advantages and I am not using images but Google Map

Comment: check this once it may usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800192/illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed-when-getsupportfragmentman

Comment: this link was posted above by @DmitryArc ;)

Comment: if it works please edit the comment 
   
 
No, it didn't help – Tomasz Kowalczyk 40 mins ago

Comment: If you copy code **exactly** from other people, even if the code is licensed under creative commons, please **at least** note that you've done so. I notice your second block of code matches **exactly** to code [here on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). Unless it's a coincidence, in which case I apologise.