# setRetainInstance(true) in onCreate fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am not holding any context in my fragment so I am using `setRetainInstance(true)` in UI fragment. can any one tell me whether this is the correct approach? Also where we should basically call `setRetainInstance` method? I mean in `onCreate` or `onActivityCreated` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to put it as simply as possible.

Your fragment, probably, holds UI elements - like:

`private TextView mView`

These UI elements get initialized in `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` method of a fragment, using the `LayoutInflater` class instance.

But this `LayoutInflater` instance uses `Activity`'s context to inflate your resources. So if your UI widgets are stored in your fragment class, they implicitly possess the `Context` of the associated activity - that is, the activity to which you've attached it to by commiting `FragmentManager`'s transaction.

Now imagine a configuration change occures (screen rotation, for example). `Activity` gets destroyed and a new one is created. Old `Activity`'s **context** normally should be garbage collected. But your retained fragment instance holds a **strong reference** to this **context** via each one of your stored UI elements, and thus this **context**  is ["reachable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object) in terms of GC, and should not be garbage-collected. A memory leak occurs.

That's why retained instance fragments should not be used as UI-fragments.

Just remember - **even if you do not store** a reference to `Context` object, like `private Context context` (that's what you asked), you might leak this context in a plenty of possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

### *Introduction: setRetainInstance(boolean)*

When you look at the [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29), you see:

- `onDestroy() will not be called` (but onDetach() still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
- `onCreate(Bundle) will not be called` since the fragment is not being re-created.
- `onAttach(Activity)` and `onActivityCreated(Bundle) will still be called`.

### *Then, where do I should use this method?*

This method is used to *retain* a fragment when the configuration change. You need to set this method in fragment at its **first creation**. When you see above that `onAttach` or `onActivityCreated` will still be called after a rotation, don't set the method inside because you will called it again. It's useless...! The best approach is to call `setRetainInstance` inside `onCreate` method, because this last will *not be called again* after a changing rotation.

### *What's the correct approach to use it?*

All depends what you want and do with your `FragmentActivity` and fragments. I'll answer with [a quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/2668136) by Alex Lockwood:

> Retained fragments can be quite useful for propagating state information — especially thread management — across activity instances. For example, a fragment can serve as a host for an instance of **Thread** or **AsyncTask**, managing its operation. See [my blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) on this topic for more information.
>
> In general, I would treat it similarly to using **onConfigurationChanged** with an **Activity**... don't use it as a bandaid just because you are too lazy to implement/handle an orientation change correctly. ***Only use it when you need to***.