# Android Fragment Animation is repeated again on Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my activity I have added the fragment by using the following code.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_to_left_in, R.anim.right_to_left_exit,R.anim.left_to_right_in,R.anim.left_to_right_exit);
DetailsFragment newFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, newFragment, "detailFragment");
ft.commit();
```

Fragment is entering,exiting, popping with the animations properly. But when I orient the device, Fragment Manager is trying to add the fragment with the same animations. It seems very odd. I don't want the animation when user orients the device.

I don't want to add `onConfigChanges='orientation'` in manifest since I want to change the fragment's layout design on orientation.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could avoid this was to *not retain* the fragment instance. In your `DetailsFragment`'s `onCreate` method use `setRetainInstance(false);`

Comment: Kudos! Its working! I am checking on other side effects(Is anything there!?) while setting setRetainInstance(false);

Comment: The problem is that the fragment will not be retained - read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/667202

Comment: Look also here - http://adblogcat.com/fragment-transition-animations-while-hiding-the-previous-fragment/

Answer (score 0):

Android re-attaches existing fragment to an activity automatically in case of orientation change. So you don't have to do it manually. You may check savedInstanceState variable in `onCreate` method of the activity for null and replace a fragment with animation only in case if it's null:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_to_left_in, R.anim.right_to_left_exit,R.anim.left_to_right_in,R.anim.left_to_right_exit);
    DetailsFragment newFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
    ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, newFragment, "detailFragment");
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My activity already has this logic. I never added the fragment again.When fragment manager tries to re-attach the fragment on orientation, it applies the animations which already stored in the transaction. (I.e which I set when fragment was added)