# How to maintain ListView fragment state after orientation/configuration change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a ListView fragment in my application that is experiencing some issues.

1. When I scroll to a specific element in the list view, then rotate the device, the list view resets to the top of the list.
2. When I enter multi-select mode in the list view, then rotate the device, the selected list items reset.

Here is my activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    protected static final String   FRAGMENT_TAG    = "TEST";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        TestFragment f = (TestFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);

        // If no fragment exists, then create a new one and add it!
        if (f == null)
        {
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder, new TestFragment(), FRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

here is main_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my TestFragment class, with the misc. content removed:

```
public class TestFragment extends ListFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Sets the list up for multiple choice selection.
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
    }
}
```

I have seen two discussions for this.  One is stating that I should be using `setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment's `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.  The other says I should be using the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle)` methods to keep track of stuff somehow.  I would like to use the `setRetainInstanceState(true)` approach, but adding that into the project like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstanceState(true);
}
```

Does not work for me.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Retaining the `Fragment` instance is not going to do what you want, as the `Activity` is still going to be recreated, and the views destroyed. If you really want to retain the original views, then you can attempt to retain the `Activity` instance by using the `configChanges` attribute in the manifest definition. However, this is not a good idea unless you really need it, and neither is it reliable, as you can only select specific configuration changes that won't restart the `Activity`, and the `Activity` may still be restarted due to the application process itself being killed and recreated.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using the configChanges attribute, for exactly the reasons you stated.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a slightly different approach to adding a `Fragment` to your `Activity`.

In your `TestActivity` class, check if the `Bundle` is null in the onCreate() method. Only add the `Fragment` if savedInstanceState is null. This will prevent your `Activity` from adding another instance of the same `Fragment` when the device's orientation is changed.

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "TEST";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) { 

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, new TestFragment(), FRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

}
```

I would suggest not using the `setRetainInstance(true)` method for a `Fragment` that has a UI. Check the StackOverflow discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/1309401) for an explanation of when to use `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: In this scenario, am I required to call setListAdapter(data) each time a rotation occurs?  I have this setup as described above mocked up in my app but I only see the an activity indicator/spinner and Loading... displayed.

However, in a sample app I quickly made that does call setListAdapter() in onActivityCreated(), this seems to work (at least it keeps the location of where I was in the list OK, not sure about selection state of the list items yet).

Comment: Okay, new update.  I have your code working in my app.  I am not sure what I was doing wrong, but I suppose that's irrelevant now.  I also noticed that the CAB title was not being kept correctly, but I was able to get that back in the `onPrepareActionMode` method, since the activity knows it was open previously, which is nice.

Comment: Are you by chance overriding onSaveInstanceState() in your Activity and not calling the super method?