# Retain Current Visible Fragment After Orientation Changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

In my application I have 3 Fragments. suppose fragment1, fragment2, and Fragment3. these three fragments hosted on single activity. there is a Navigation drawer available to navigate each fragment. and Fragment1 is the default fragment, ie., Fragment1 is visible when the application starts. the problem is when the orientation of phone changes the current visible fragment goes out and the default fragment shows, because the activity restarts. I am keeping a the tag of current visible fragment's tag in bundle, and checks in onCreate method. but I cant create Fragment object of corresponding fragment by tag.

**onCreate**

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFragment = new Fragment1();
            showFragment(mFragment, FRAGMENT1_TAG);
        } else {
            String tag = savedInstanceState.getString(CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            mFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

            if (mFragment != null)
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment, tag).commit();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something went wrong, please restart application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**onSaveInstanceState**

```
String fragmentTag = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame).getTag();
        dataOut.putString(CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG, fragmentTag);
```

when the orientation changes I am getting  a null pointer exception, that is the mFragment is null, how can I resolve this

**UPDATE**

```
 public static void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        mFragmentTag = tag;

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, mFragmentTag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean

Comment: that is about restoring fragment state, but i have to keep the activity state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to prevent the activity from recreating by setting
`android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` in your manifest file.

### UPDATE

You need to call to: `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` when overriding the **onSaveInstanceState** method

Comment: actually I am making some layout changes when orientation changes. so I can't lock orientation

Comment: can you post the code of `showFragment` function please?

Comment: Are you calling to `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` in your onSaveInstanceState function?

Comment: That is the problem... The fragment manager doesn't save its state. Add the call to super and everything will be fine. You should always call to super when you override the life cycle methods.

Comment: Not a good practice: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Answer (score 2):

Keep the name of the class of your Fragments in the Bundle.

Then recreate your Fragment with the name of the class, using the static method [instantiate](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)).

```
String name = savedInstanceState.getString(CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate (Activity.this, "com.example." + name);
```

The method expects the full name (package included).

Comment: but in that case you will lose your backstack info , isn't there a way to kepp that also ?