# Why does FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT) not return null

Tags: android, fragment

I read this http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html. And I played the example code in the link. To my surprise, fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT) does not return null when I rotate the phone, if I remove setRetainInstance(true) in the TaskFragment.onCreate(). I copied the code here with one line change (remove setRetainInstance(true)).

Please explain why fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT) does not return null in this case.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TaskFragment.TaskCallbacks {

  private static final String TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT = "task_fragment";

  private TaskFragment mTaskFragment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);

    if (mTaskFragment == null) {
      mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
      fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPreExecute() { }

  @Override
  public void onProgressUpdate(int percent) { }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled() {  }

  @Override
  public void onPostExecute() { }
}


public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {
  interface TaskCallbacks {
    void onPreExecute();
    void onProgressUpdate(int percent);
    void onCancelled();
    void onPostExecute();
  }

  private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
  private DummyTask mTask;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// I remove this call to produce the problem
 //   setRetainInstance(true);

    mTask = new DummyTask();
    mTask.execute();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
  }

  private class DummyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {   
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
      for (int i = 0; !isCancelled() && i < 100; i++) {
        SystemClock.sleep(100);
        publishProgress(i);
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... percent) {
      if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onProgressUpdate(percent[0]);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
      if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onCancelled();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
      if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onPostExecute();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetRetainInstance` controls whether the entire fragment (and its contents) is retained in memory or whether it is recreated as a new Fragment from its `Bundle`.

The only time it would return null is the very first time the app is run. After that it has been added to the `FragmentManager` and is always available. (Rotating the device does not clear the `FragmentManager` regardless of whether you use `SetRetainInstance` or not)

You seem to think that `SetRetainInstance` controls whether the fragment is kept in the `FragmentManager` or not. It does not.

In your example, the AsyncTask starts running the first time the Fragment is created. SetRetainInstance is used to stop the OnDestroy method of the Fragment being called. After an orientation change, the fragment and its running task is still in the FragmentManager and the task is still running.  Without SetRetainInstance, when the Orientation change occurs, the fragment is destroyed and recreated from its bundle when you retrieve it from the FragmentManager. This puts the AsyncTask in a delicate state as the task could still be running even if its hosting Fragment has been destroyed possibly leading to a crash.

See this question for a more in depth explanation.

[Understanding Fragment's setRetainInstance(boolean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume from your answer that it is recreated from its Bundle when SetRetainInstance is used. However, I have removed SetRetainInstance in my case. The 1st instance of TaskFragment will be destroyed, but how is it  found by findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT)?

Comment: Why would you assume it would be destroyed? As I said, it will remain in the FragmentManager regardless of whether you use SetRetainInstance or not. If you want it to be removed then you must remove it yourself. You are simply misunderstanding the function of SetRetainInstance.

Comment: I may misunderstand the function of SetRetainInstance. However, if we can always get the instance of TaskFragment back, is the only purpose to call SetRetainInstance to avoid onCreate() being called in the fragment?

Comment: Almost, it stops OnDestroy being called. As the Fragment is not destroyed, there is no need to call OnCreate again.