# Hidden fragment dont loose the state but when hiding fragment on onSaveInstanceState the state lost, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onsaveinstancestate

My application has a ‍‍‍‍`BottomNavigation` with 4 tabs, I had a fragment for every tab and add all of this 4 fragment to `FragmentManager`. When one of this tab is selected, I hide other fragment and show the fragment of this tab.
**My problem is, when the screen is rotated, hidden fragments don't lose the state, and showing tab loose the state**.
I try to hide the showing fragment in `onSaveInstanceState` and show it in `onCreateView` but it didn't work!
Why the hidden fragment saves their own state but showing fragment lost it? And how I can use this feature to save state of showing fragment?

My application using **nested fragments**, I have 4 main fragment and showing another page in that fragment I replace it with other fragment and save replaced fragment to backstack of `childFragmentManager` for saving backstack of every tab.
When I rotate the screen, only showing tab going back to first fragment like first time this tab is show, but other tabs saving their stats!
I want to save the state of showing fragment like others, how can I do it?

Comment: You have single container right?? Can you post your code

Comment: Yes, I have a single container, a `FrameLayout` for all of the fragments. I want to know what the difference between hiding fragments and showing fragments, and how I can use this feature for my showing fragment?

Comment: Try calling setRetainInstance(true) in your fragments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean

Comment: I use `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreateView`  of fragment, but it doe's not work!

Comment: Rather than hiding fragment y dont you replace it ?

Comment: `FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();  
transaction.hide(oldFragment);  
transaction.show(newFragment);  transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);  transaction.commit();
` this is my code for navigating between tabs