# How to make ExoPlayer resume video playback when device rotates without using android:configChanges

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm working on a project that uses ExoPlayer to stream videos from a URL. But there is an issue with my code. When the device is rotated, the entire video is restarted.
Using `android:configChanges` fixes it, but I'm not supposed to use that.
I used `onSaveInstanceState()` to cache all required data such as playerPosition, currentWindow, and setPlayWhenReady; and I retrieve it accordingly. But it still doesn't work as expected. How do I fix this?
Here is the entire Fragment class that has this issue:

```
package com.app.shubhamjhunjhunwala.thebakingapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.shubhamjhunjhunwala.thebakingapp.Objects.Dish;
import com.app.shubhamjhunjhunwala.thebakingapp.Objects.Step;
import com.github.paolorotolo.expandableheightlistview.ExpandableHeightListView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.parceler.Parcels;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ExtraDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public ExtraDetailsFragment() {}

    public boolean twoPaneLayout;

    public Dish dish;
    public int stepID;

    public String videoURL;

    public SimpleExoPlayerView playerView;
    public SimpleExoPlayer player;
    public long playerPosition;
    public boolean playWhenReady;
    public int currentWindow;

    public TextView textView;

    public static boolean hasShownVideoInFullScreen = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView;

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra_details_fragment, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            dish =  Parcels.unwrap(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("Dish"));
            stepID = savedInstanceState.getInt("ID");
            twoPaneLayout = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("TwoPane");

            playerPosition = savedInstanceState.getLong("PlayerPosition", 0);
            playWhenReady = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("PlayWhenReady", true);
            currentWindow = savedInstanceState.getInt("CurrentWindow", 0);
            Log.d("Player Position", Long.toString(playerPosition));
        }

        Log.d("Details Fragment", dish.toString());

        playerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.details_text_view);

        Step[] steps = dish.getSteps();
        textView.setText(steps[stepID].getDescription());

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putParcelable("Dish", Parcels.wrap(dish));
        outState.putInt("ID", stepID);
        outState.putBoolean("TwoPane", twoPaneLayout);
        outState.putLong("PlayerPosition", playerPosition);
        outState.putBoolean("PlayWhenReady", playWhenReady);
        outState.putInt("CurrentWindow", currentWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE && !twoPaneLayout && !hasShownVideoInFullScreen) {
            hasShownVideoInFullScreen = true;
            playVideoInFullScreen();
        }*/
        if ((Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null)) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
    }

    public void initializePlayer() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(getContext()), new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());

        playerView.setPlayer(player);

        Step[] steps = dish.getSteps();
        String imageURL = "";
        videoURL = steps[stepID].getVideoURL();
        imageURL = steps[stepID].getImageURL();

        if (!videoURL.equals("")) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoURL);
            MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
            player.seekTo(currentWindow, playerPosition);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        } else if (videoURL.equals("") && !imageURL.equals("")) {
            final String finalImageURL = imageURL;
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    try {
                        bitmap = Picasso.with(getContext()).load(finalImageURL).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        playerView.setDefaultArtwork(bitmap);
                    } else {
                        playerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Video Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }.execute();
        } else {
            playerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Video Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void playVideoInFullScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FullScreenVideoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Video URL", videoURL);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playerPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
        return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer")).createMediaSource(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not supposed to use android:configChanges?

Comment: This project is a part of Udacity's Android Developer Nanodegree Program, and it is against the guidelines. Also, on the Android Developer's page, it is mentioned that configChanges must be used only when there is no work-around left.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set fragments retain instance as true:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

There is no more need to work with onSaveInstanceState() or configChanges.

Some useful information about:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11318942/6193843

Comment: The video still reinitializes

Comment: According to official docs your fragment must not be putted to back stack to use retain instance