# Android Fragment - how to get the "mWho" value?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

If one prints a Fragment:

`println("fragment: ${Fragment()}")`

it prints out:

`Fragment{8d157db} (d63150f2-7497-4c04-9214-d20c3ccaba34)`

Looking at the implementation of the `toString()`, I can see:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
    Class<?> cls = getClass();
    sb.append(cls.getSimpleName());
    sb.append("{");
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this)));
    sb.append("}");
    sb.append(" (");
    sb.append(mWho);
    if (mFragmentId != 0) {
        sb.append(" id=0x");
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(mFragmentId));
    }
    if (mTag != null) {
        sb.append(" tag=");
        sb.append(mTag);
    }
    sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

So the `UUID` it's printing is from `mWho` variable which gets generated using:

```
// Internal unique name for this fragment;
@NonNull
String mWho = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Is there a way to get this value for use as the `tag` when using `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag`? Getting it without parsing the `toString` string.

I am asking this because right now I have my own custom uniqueUUID which I use for restoring a fragment using `retainInstance`. If I can get the `mWho`, I won't need my own custom code for the uniqueUUID.

Comment: Be careful as `mWho` can be mutated with configuration changes

Comment: @Zain When I use `retainInstance` for the fragment, then it doesn't change as far as I can tell.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use an instance-specific identifier for a tag. Don't get too cozy with `setRetainInstance()`: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1159084

Comment: What does "which I use for restoring a fragment using retainInstance" mean? Can you explain what you're actually doing?

Comment: @ianhanniballake `retainInstance` in the fragment prevents it from being destroyed when the configuration changes (orientation change for example). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean

Comment: I wrote fragments, so yes, I know how that part works. I'm trying to figure out why you think you need a unique tag and how you are using `findFragmentByTag` at all.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using it similar to how it's explained in this link. I use the `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag` to get the fragment which was created before device orientation changes. This way I don't have to recreate the data or use anything in `onSaveInstanceState` except the TAG which I use the `mWho` for: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/retaining-objects-using-a-fragment/

Comment: So...why do you need a UUID based tag at all? You could use `"blah"` and it would work exactly the same?

Comment: @ianhanniballake when I add another activity with a different fragment instance, wouldn't it end up conflicting?

Comment: Each activity is completely separate; there's no conflict. Please include your code where you create your retained fragment, retrieve your retained fragment, and how you use your retained fragment. It really seems like this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) that has a much better way of solving your actual underlying problem.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is the `supportFragmentManager` unique for every Activity instance? For example when an Activity starts a new activity, is the `supportFragmentManager` for the new activity unique for itself than the previous activity? You are probably right about the XY Problem thing. I am relatively new to Android so I might be using wrong practice.

Comment: As I already mentioned, every activity is completely separate from every other activity - the `supportFragmentManager` in one activity is unique to just that activity and a different activity will get a completely different `supportFragmentManager`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake ah, then I don't need this unique tag. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this using reflection and lazy variable:

```
val who: String by lazy {
    println("Trying to get who!")
    var toReturn = ""
    try {
        println("Fields: ${javaClass.superclass.superclass}")
        toReturn = javaClass.superclass.superclass.getDeclaredField("mWho").let {
            it.isAccessible = true
            it.get(this)
        } as String
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        println("Exception getting who: $e")
    }
    toReturn
}
```

Note the use of `superclass.superclass` because I placed this in a subclass of `Fragment`. The use of `lazy` prevents the use of reflection each time it's required as this value doesn't change once initialized.

Comment: Do not use reflection to access private values of the class - these are private specifically because they are not for your usage.