# Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

(Edit)

**TabClubActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e("First", "First");

    setContentView(R.layout.tab_club_layout);  ---> 140th error line in logcat

    Log.e("Second", "Second");

    MapFragment fragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map = fragment.getMap();
    fragment.onResume();

    ................

  }
```

As you see in the below log it is printing "First" log statement and not printing the "Second" log statement.

So I am sure the problem with the layout.

**Stacktrace:**

```
06-23 06:05:21.476: E/First(11700): First


06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.steve/com.app.steve.TabClubActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #175: Error inflating class fragment
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2122)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:756)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:420)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:161)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:549)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #175: Error inflating class fragment
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at com.app.steve.TabClubActivity.onCreate(TabClubActivity.java:140)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     ... 17 more
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:618)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     ... 32 more
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.steve-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:604)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     ... 36 more
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):         ... 38 more
06-23 04:54:35.492: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFou
```

**tab_club_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layout_common_ash"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

..................
..................

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/add_club_layout"
            layout="@layout/club_add_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/search_club_layout"
            layout="@layout/club_search_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this below layout, I am using **mapFragment**:

**club_search_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layout_common_ash"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  ....................
  ....................

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_club_search_card_flip_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_club_search_top"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_club_search_card_flip_front"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_main_activity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onCardClick" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_club_search_card_flip_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onCardClick"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_club_search_card_flip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" >
            </ListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_club_search_card_flip_no_records"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/club_search_card_flip_no_records"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using google map library revision 29.

I am using adapter class inside TabClubActivity.That means I am using adapter class as a inner class.

I am using Eclipse version 21.I tried many [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016632/unable-to-instantiate-fragment) post.But couldn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend few days.but can't resolve this issue in Eclipse tool.Then I tried with Android studio.

Map is working fine.Issue has been resolved only in studio.In eclipse many times google map library issue happened to me.But when I moved to studio, my code is working fine.

Error occurred due to changes in new OS changed with eclipse tool and sdk.It might be google map library issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does your activity imports *android.app.fragment* ?

If so, try with *android.v4.app.fragment* instead.

Later on, you'll need to use *getSupportFragmentManager* and not *getFragment*.

Answer (score 0):

change  `getFragmentManager()` to  `getSupportFragmentManager()`.This Exception because you are using `imports android.app.Fragment`.Replace with  imports `android.v4.app.Fragment`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e("First", "First");

    setContentView(R.layout.tab_club_layout);  ---> 140th error line in logcat

    Log.e("Second", "Second"); 

    MapFragment fragment = ((MapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map = fragment.getMap();
    fragment.onResume();

    ................ 

  }
```